# How to enable or disable button according to what summernote have as text inside?

Tags: jquery, laravel, summernote

I  have a form wizard in the first step there is summernote and a next button by the id "change_summernote" if the summernote contains text enable else disable (even after user enters text and then delete it )
this is my code:

```
$(".summernote").on("summernote.keyup", function (we,e) { 
                if(e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8)
                {
                    if ( jQuery(".summernote").summernote("code") == '') 
                    {
                        //this line is not working
                        jQuery('#change_summernote').attr("disabled");

                    } else {

                        jQuery('#change_summernote').removeAttr("disabled");
                        //No guarantee it isn't mindless gibberish, sorry.

                    }   
                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery('#change_summernote').removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
```

the part when the next button is diabled if the all text inside summernote is deleted is not working

Comment: try `jQuery('#change_summernote').attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way of setting attribute using JQuery.

```
jQuery('#change_summernote').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: shoud i use attr or prop ?

Comment: disabled is an html tag 'attribute' https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp so use  `attr`